# unmet dependencies - gedit

Tags: ubuntu

I recently had some issue with the text editor (gedit 3.8.3) so i tried to uninstall/reinstall it the problem is, that when I use the command 'apt-get install gedit' the terminal show me an error:

```
computer@computer:~$ sudo apt-get install gedit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gedit : Depends: libgtksourceview-3.0-0 (>= 3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gedit-common (< 3.5) but 3.8.3-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have spent the whole day trying to find a solution

Can someone help me solve this problem? I am using zorin os 8

Comment: Does that message give you any clues? Why don't you try installing the mentioned packages

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see the list of held packages by:

```
sudo apt-mark showhold
```

and then un-hold them by

```
sudo apt-mark unhold <package name>
```

After that, you should be able to remove the conflicting package (it seems to be npm) and then reinstall all.